# Ticks Per Second : Alternative for QueryPerformanceFrequency

Tags: windows, mfc, gettickcount

QueryPerformanceFrequency crashes on our system,

Is it feasible to use flowwing piece of code as an alternative

```
LARGE_INTEGER pCount;
LARGE_INTEGER pCount2;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&pCount);
Sleep(1000);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&pCount2);
pCount2.QuadPart-pCount.QuadPart;
```

will the difference b/w pCount2 and pCount give me tick count  ??

Or Do we have any other alternative function which gives tickCount ??

Comment: The problem is that Sleep is not very precise. It depends on the system clock, which has a typical resolution of 10 or 15 ms. Also, it sleeps at least the given time, not precisely that time. So you'll get "ticks per *about* one second", not "ticks per second".

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "QueryPerformanceFrequency crashes"? Does it throw an exception, does it show a BSOD...? "Crash" can mean a variety of things and each will have a different solution. In fact, QueryPerformanceFrequency should return the frequency or zero if it's not supported. A "crash" might be something to investigate further.

Comment: This crash occurred after we applied a windows patch but it works fine with standalone application.
We have also tried memory alignment way too

Comment: This crash occurred after we applied a windows patch but it works fine with standalone application.
these line of code crashed.

 
    LARGE_INTEGER res;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&res);


We have also tried memory alignment way too.
When we tried creating  res on heap, it didnt crash but we got junk values and API returns FALSE.
GetLastError - > Invalid access to memory location

Comment: You should not ask for an alternative. You should rather fix your code. A call to `QueryPerformanceFrequency` does not crash. Errors are reported through the `BOOL`ean return value and `GetLastError` if it failed.

Comment: I just stepped though the QueryPerformanceFrequency function and I didn't see how this function could crash if the parameter passed to it points to valid memory. Try doing the same. This might give you a clue.

Comment: Did you test your crash of QueryPerformanceFrequency() only in your (possibly large) application or also in a standalone mini test program? In my experience, when stuff like this happens, the bug is elsewhere and your memory is corrupted by other sections of your code.